# Policy API support

Tags: box-api

Are there any box-api's for applying policies on any of the activity? For eg., collaboration/sharing restriction per user basis, or file type upload restriction per user or organization level.

We have an enterprise account, we want to enable such policies. As an admin, I was wondering what are the APIs available for me.

Thanks in Advance
-Praveen

Answer (score 0):

This sort of functionality is currently only available through the admin console web UI and not through APIs yet.